# Following a tutorial on youtube about fpp player movement/camera movement, and i got this frustrating error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Assets\playermovement.cs(22,28): error CS0019: Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector3' and 'int'

pls help

```
if (isGrounded && velocity < 0)
     {
         velocity.y = -2f;
     }
```

Comment: [Compiler Error CS0019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0019)   `Vector3` is not an `int`.  You probably want the magnitude of the `Vector3`.  Have you studied linear algebra?  This is a bit of a critical topic if you mean to program in 3 dimensions.

Comment: [Vector3.magnitude](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-magnitude.html)

Comment: You can't compare 3 floats (Vector3) with one int (0). Get the magnitude or one float of the vector and then compare

Comment: Thanks for your Comment, now i understand a bit of the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a single number indicating how fast the object is travelling, in this case `velocity` is a `Vector3` containing three numbers (x, y and z values) which indicate both the speed and the direction of travel in 3D space.

If you were wanting a single number indicating the object's current speed (the length of the vector essentially), you could use `velocity.magnitude`:

```
if (isGrounded && velocity.magnitude < 0)
{
    velocity.y = -2f;
}
```

However that wouldn't make sense in this case as the magnitude will never be less than 0 (slower than motionless). I think what you were probably intending to do is check the object's velocity on the Y axis -- i.e. "is the object moving downwards". For that purpose, use `velocity.y` for the `if` statement:

```
if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
{
    velocity.y = -2f;
}
```

Comment: Your a Legend, Thanks for saving my life lol, have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Unity supports only multiplication of Vector3 by a number. But you can add two vectors or subtract one from another.Thank you hope it can help you